# How to ignore Excel Query Errors

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am using Excel's Power Query for data analysis. In the file that contains the original data, there are about 15 columns. The query is only pulling data based on one of the columns. For example, the column contains either 'A' or 'B'. I want all data of that row if that certain column is a 'B'.

[image: Example of my Excel data]

The problem is in Column A, all of the names are text except for row 5. It's a decimal. Excel Power Query will throw an error and say it doesn't match the other rows. It will still query the data and pull it into another file, but with throwing the errors.

Some of my data will not match like in this example. So is there a way to ignore these errors? I still want the data from the original file; I just want to tell Excel that it's okay if the row data doesn't match other rows. I've formatted the entire column to one type and that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Can't recreate this error from that data - a decimal can be read as a text value with no errors. [Edit] your post to include your code which causes an error with that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors` to remove the rows that have errors, or `Table.ReplaceErrorValues` if you want to replace the error value in the cell with something else.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: on a `Foo` column of type `Number` I had all *numeric* values, except some that were just *text*, and on these text values Power Query gave me "Error".

To fix it I did this: I opened "`Power Query Editor`" -> "`Advanced Editor`", and I made this replacement:

FROM: `Table.TransformColumnTypes(.....{"Foo", Int64.Type}....)`

TO:   `Table.TransformColumnTypes(.....{"Foo", type text}....)`

So I changed the type of Foo from `Int64.Type` -> to `type text`, and the error disappeared, so I can see both numeric and text values without any error.